# how to do dynamic dropdown in shiny from imported data?

Tags: r, shiny, bar-chart

In R shiny I have imported the .xlsx file using the below code, I have to select the header attributes to the drop-down and want to do the bar chart using that?? I am new to R can anyone help me??

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("File Upload"),
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput('file1', 'Choose xlsx file',
                    accept = c(".xlsx")
          )
        ),
        mainPanel(
          tableOutput('contents'))
      )
    ),
    server = function(input, output){
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        inFile <- input$file1

        if(is.null(inFile))
          return(NULL)
        file.rename(inFile$datapath,
                    paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""))
        read_excel(paste(inFile$datapath, ".xlsx", sep=""), 1)
      })
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: so to confirm, you'd like to show the column names (which is the header) as the dropdown values?

Comment: To make a `ui.R` element that reacts to your file uploaded you will have to make the ui element in `server.R` using the `renderUI` command which can then be displayed using `uiOuput` in `ui.R`. [Here is a link](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) to an example of `renderUI` command. Is that enough for you to go on?